# GridView: SelectedIndexChanged event fires before RowDeleting event in firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, gridview

i have this construct for a gridview with `AutoGenerateDeleteButton` to `true` and couple of events like this:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdViewOrders" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" OnRowDeleting="grdViewOrders_RowDeleting" AutoGenerateSelectButton="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdViewOrders_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDataBound="grdViewOrders_RowDataBound"></asp:GridView>
```

I Added a couple of jQuery lines to make the hyperlink display a glyphicon instead of the "delete" text.

Rendered:
[image: Rendered Gridview as viewed in developer tools]

Code which adds `Select` functionality without the actual select hyperlink.:

```
protected void grdViewOrders_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
         e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(grdViewOrders, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
         e.Row.Attributes["style"] = "cursor:pointer";
     }

}
```

Code that runs on Pressing the `Delete` hyperlink

```
protected void grdViewOrders_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    //Get Row id and run Delete Query
}
```

All works good and fine, except on firefox.
On firefox Clicking the `Delete` hyperlink triggers the `SelectedIndexChanged` event instead of the `RowDeleting` event. Clicking on the row also triggers the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Has firefox failed to detect the hyperlink's function or what i dont know, but i want the respective funcitons to be triggered like it happens on rest of the browsers...

Alternative would be letting the user select the entry fist and then displaying a delete button elsewhere and having a hidden field to know which row was selected by the user. But having a button alongside the entry would be easier for the user (who uses firefox).

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: What happens if you remove those `couple of jQuery lines`? Does it work with FireFox then?

Comment: Yeah it works then.. but i need both functionality.. especially the select functionality without the `select` button

Comment: But now you know the problem is in your jQuery. Check that for possible mistakes. You are probably replacing the `javascript:__doPostBack(...` content with incorrect code.